# Unable to start mongod... (no space left on device)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Anyone know how to fix this? Exception is no space left on the device but all of my files only used 600mb/10GB.... I did restart mongod, --repair, uninstall and install but none of it works... Ple

> 2018-10-03T05:42:32.011+0000 I CONTROL [initandlisten] MongoDB
>   starting : pid=2288 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=itemtory
>   2018-10-03T05:42:32.011+0000 I CONTROL [initandlisten] db version
>   v3.2.21 2018-10-03T05:42:32.011+0000 I CONTROL [initandlisten] git
>   version: 1ab1010737145ba3761318508ff65ba74dfe8155
>   2018-10-03T05:42:32.011+0000 I CONTROL [initandlisten] OpenSSL
>   version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g 1 Mar 2016 2018-10-03T05:42:32.012+0000 I
>   CONTROL [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
>   2018-10-03T05:42:32.012+0000 I CONTROL [initandlisten] modules: none
>   2018-10-03T05:42:32.012+0000 I CONTROL [initandlisten] build
>   environment: 2018-10-03T05:42:32.012+0000 I CONTROL [initandlisten]
>   distmod: ubuntu1604 2018-10-03T05:42:32.012+0000 I CONTROL
>   [initandlisten] distarch: x86_64 2018-10-03T05:42:32.012+0000 I
>   CONTROL [initandlisten] target_arch: x86_64
>   2018-10-03T05:42:32.012+0000 I CONTROL [initandlisten] options: {}
>   2018-10-03T05:42:32.037+0000 I - [initandlisten] Detected data files
>   in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the
>   active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'. 2018-10-03T05:42:32.037+0000 W
>   - [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty. 2018-10-03T05:42:32.037+0000 W STORAGE [initandlisten]
>   Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
>   2018-10-03T05:42:32.038+0000 I STORAGE [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open
>   config:
>   create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress), 2018-10-03T05:42:32.135+0000 I STORAGE [initandlisten] WiredTiger
>   [1538545352:135307][2288:0x7fbc2fb35c80], txn-recover: Main recovery
>   loop: starting at 6/128 2018-10-03T05:42:32.135+0000 I STORAGE
>   [initandlisten] WiredTiger [1538545352:135922][2288:0x7fbc2fb35c80],
>   txn-recover: Recovering log 6 through 7 2018-10-03T05:42:32.137+0000 I
>   STORAGE [initandlisten] WiredTiger
>   [1538545352:137457][2288:0x7fbc2fb35c80], file:sizeStorer.wt,
>   txn-recover: Recovering log 7 through 7 2018-10-03T05:42:32.216+0000 I
>   CONTROL [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as
>   the root user, which is not recommended. 2018-10-03T05:42:32.216+0000
>   I CONTROL [initandlisten] 2018-10-03T05:42:32.217+0000 I CONTROL
>   [initandlisten] 2018-10-03T05:42:32.217+0000 I CONTROL [initandlisten]
>   ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'. 2018-10-03T05:42:32.217+0000 I CONTROL [initandlisten] ** We suggest
>   setting it to 'never' 2018-10-03T05:42:32.217+0000 I CONTROL
>   [initandlisten] 2018-10-03T05:42:32.218+0000 I FTDC [initandlisten]
>   Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory
>   '/data/db/diagnostic.data' 2018-10-03T05:42:32.218+0000 I NETWORK
>   [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
>   2018-10-03T05:42:32.223+0000 I NETWORK
>   [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization
>   worker 2018-10-03T05:42:33.000+0000 W FTDC [ftdc] Uncaught exception
>   in 'UnknownError: Caught std::exception of type
>   boost::filesystem::filesystem_error:
>   boost::filesystem::create_directory: No space left on device:
>   "/data/db/diagnostic.data"' in full-time diagnostic data capture
>   subsystem. Shutting down the full-time diagnostic data capture
>   subsystem.

`df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            991M     0  991M   0% /dev
tmpfs           201M   16M  185M   8% /run
/dev/vda1        25G    25G    0 100% /
tmpfs          1001M     0 1001M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1001M     0 1001M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15      105M  3.4M  102M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           201M     0  201M   0% /run/user/0
```

`df -i /data/db`:

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/vda1      3225600 192164 3033436    6% /
```

Comment: Either it's some kind of insufficient permission situation, or you forgot to count some files. Run `df -h`, what does it say?

Comment: Running out of inodes (although the last time something like that happened to me must have been 20-odd years ago)? `df -i /data/db`

Comment: @robertklep /dev/vdal 25G/25G... Any way I could fix this?

Comment: @Terence can you add the full output for both suggested `df` commands to your question?

Comment: @robertklep okay, attached to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The last command (`df -i /data/db`) shows that `/data/db` is located on the root (`/`) partition.

The first command (`df -h`) shows that that partition is 100% full. So that's the reason why you're getting a *"No space left on device"* error.

I'm not sure where you're getting "600mb/10GB" from, the root partition's size is 25GB.